# Pulling data from an API into a Google Sheet using Apps Script, but only 50 lines of data are showing up

Tags: google-apps-script

For context, the code is pulling information from a 3rd party API a google sheet.

I am working to pull information about handheld devices from a site to a google sheet. Some of the information writes to the google sheet but stops at 50 lines. The API returns about 4900 lines of data, which I have already verified are being pulled from the API.

I am not sure whether it is the chunk array that is causing the issue, or some other issue. I have read about a pagetoken, but am unsure how I would implement it in the code.

Can someone please help me to get the rest of the information to the google sheet. Is there something that I need to add or change?

```
function chunkArray(myArray, chunk_size){
var index = 0;
var arrayLength = myArray.length;
var tempArray = ;

for (index = 0; index < arrayLength; index += chunk_size) {
    myChunk = myArray.slice(index, index+chunk_size);
    // Do something if you want with the group
    tempArray.push(myChunk);
}

return tempArray;

}

function flatten(arrayOfArrays){
return [].concat.apply([], arrayOfArrays);
}

function pullInformation(){

var token = 'token';

var options = {
 'method': 'GET',
 'contentType': 'application/JSON',
 'accept': 'application/json',
 'headers': {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token},

};
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var data = [];
var start = 0;

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('', options);
var numberOfData = 200;
var aOneName = "$type";
var data = response.getContentText();
var json = JSON.parse(data);
var rows = [Object.keys(json)]; // Retrieve entry column.
var toRows = rows[0].length;
var toRows = toRows + 1;
Logger.log("A2:A" + toRows);
Logger.log(rows);
var rowsflate = flatten(rows);
var rowstocols  = chunkArray(rowsflate, 1);
Logger.log(rowstocols);
sheet.getRange("A2:A" + toRows).setValues(rowstocols); // sets column of IDs
sheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue(aOneName); // A1 name    
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var headers = json[rows[0][2]];
Logger.log(headers);
var getHeaders = [Object.keys(headers)];
Logger.log(getHeaders);
sheet.getRange(1,2,getHeaders.length,getHeaders[0].length).setValues(getHeaders); // Put values to Spreadsheet.
var content = [];
var temp = [];
for (var i = 0; i < rows[0].length; i++) {
  var temp2 = [Object.values(json[rows[0][i]])];// Retrieve values to be split.
  content.push(flatten(temp2));
}
Logger.log(content);
var columncount1= rows[0].length;
Logger.log(columncount1);
var columncount2 = getHeaders[0].length;
Logger.log(columncount2);
sheet.getRange(2,2,columncount1,columncount2).setValues(content); // Put values to Spreadsheet.

}
```